# Calculating area of intersection part in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, intersection, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I would like to ask why I can't get the area value of the intersection even though I can see the intersection of the flooded area and the cropland part on the map.
I'm not sure if it's a problem with the way my code is calculated or a problem with the threshold selection.

I attached my code as follows:

```
var geometry = ee.FeatureCollection("users/miaohu828/f_Dongxihuxuzhihuqu");
var before_start= '2020-06-20';
var before_end='2020-07-10';

var after_start='2020-08-23';
var after_end='2020-09-10';


var polarization = "VH"; 
var pass_direction = "ASCENDING"; 
var difference_threshold = 1.25; 

var aoi = ee.FeatureCollection(geometry);

var collection= ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode','IW'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', polarization))
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass',pass_direction)) 
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('resolution_meters',10))
  .filterBounds(aoi)
  .select(polarization);
  
var before_collection = collection.filterDate(before_start, before_end);
var after_collection = collection.filterDate(after_start,after_end);


      function dates(imgcol){
        var range = imgcol.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.minMax(), ["system:time_start"]);
        var printed = ee.String('from ')
          .cat(ee.Date(range.get('min')).format('YYYY-MM-dd'))
          .cat(' to ')
          .cat(ee.Date(range.get('max')).format('YYYY-MM-dd'));
        return printed;
      }

var before = before_collection.mosaic().clip(aoi);
var after = after_collection.mosaic().clip(aoi);

var smoothing_radius = 50;
var before_filtered = before.focal_mean(smoothing_radius, 'circle', 'meters');
var after_filtered = after.focal_mean(smoothing_radius, 'circle', 'meters');

var difference = after_filtered.divide(before_filtered);

var threshold = difference_threshold;
var difference_binary = difference.gt(threshold);
var swater = ee.Image('JRC/GSW1_0/GlobalSurfaceWater').select('seasonality');
      var swater_mask = swater.gte(10).updateMask(swater.gte(10));
      
      var flooded_mask = difference_binary.where(swater_mask,0);
      var flooded = flooded_mask.updateMask(flooded_mask);
     var connections = flooded.connectedPixelCount();    
      var flooded = flooded.updateMask(connections.gte(25));
     var DEM = ee.Image('WWF/HydroSHEDS/03VFDEM');
      var terrain = ee.Algorithms.Terrain(DEM);
      var slope = terrain.select('slope');
      var flooded = flooded.updateMask(slope.lt(5));

var flood_pixelarea = flooded.select(polarization)
  .multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea());

var flood_stats = flood_pixelarea.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),              
  geometry: aoi,
  scale: 10, // native resolution 
  //maxPixels: 1e9,
  bestEffort: true
  });

var flood_area_ha = flood_stats
  .getNumber(polarization)
  .divide(10000)
  .round(); 
print(flood_area_ha,'flood_Area_ha')

var LC = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD12Q1')
  .filterDate('2014-01-01',after_end)
  .sort('system:index',false)
  .select("LC_Type1")
  .first()
  .clip(aoi);

var cropmask = LC
  .eq(12)
  .or(LC.eq(14))
var cropland = LC
  .updateMask(cropmask)
  
var MODISprojection = LC.projection();

var flooded_res = flooded
    .reproject({
    crs: MODISprojection
  });

var cropland_affected = flooded_res
  .updateMask(cropland)

var crop_pixelarea = cropland_affected
  .multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()); //calcuate the area of each pixel 

var crop_stats = crop_pixelarea.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(), //sum all pixels with area information                
  geometry: aoi,
  scale: 500,
  maxPixels: 1e9
  });
  
var crop_area_ha = crop_stats
  .getNumber(polarization)
  .divide(10000);
print(crop_area_ha,'crop_area_ha')
Map.centerObject(aoi,8);
Map.addLayer(after_filtered, {min:-25,max:0}, 'After Flood',1);
// Cropland
var croplandVis = {
  min: 0,
  max: 14.0,
  palette: ['30b21c'],
};
Map.addLayer(cropland, croplandVis, 'Cropland',0)
// Flooded areas
Map.addLayer(flooded,{palette:"0000FF"},'Flooded areas');
// Affected cropland
Map.addLayer(cropland_affected, croplandVis, 'Affected Cropland');
```

[image: Green part is the cropland, the blue part is the flood extent]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you reprojected the flooded area to the MODIS projection and when it's computed in that projection, there is no flooding.

Don't use reproject; you don't need it anywhere in this code.